# Find the smallest positive integral value of $n$ satisfying the inequality below

Tags: inequality

> Find the smallest positive integral value of $n$ satisfying the inequality $$\sqrt{\frac{n-2011}{2012}}-\sqrt{\frac{n-2012}{2011}} < \sqrt[3]{\frac{n-2013}{2011}}-\sqrt[3]{\frac{n-2011}{2013}}$$

If we take $t=2012$ and $n-t=x$
We get $$\sqrt{\frac{x+1}{t}}-\sqrt{\frac{x}{t-1}} < \sqrt[3]{\frac{x-1}{t-1}}-\sqrt[3]{\frac{x+1}{t+1}}$$
What to do next?
Answer is $4024$

Comment: solution: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h491126